# Fading classes into each other by multiple using of switchClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, fade

I want a result like this:

Fade `border-color` of `#mydiv` from `.color1` to `.color2`, `.color2` to `.color3`, `.color3` to `.color4` and then `.color4` to `.color1`.

Why shouldn't the following code work?

```
$( "#mydiv" ).switchClass( "color1", "color2", 1000 ).switchClass( "color2",
"color3", 1000 ).switchClass( "color3", "color4", 1000 ).switchClass(
"color4", "color1", 1000 );
```

Dear guys, also let me know if that's easier to get it done using `CSS transition`.

Comment: Are you looking for animation effect? You can do with css transitions or jQuery animation effects

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ujDkf/1/ to get an idea

Comment: Your code line works perfectly fine here http://jsfiddle.net/betdzroz/ What issue are you having with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Solution might help you.

```
<div id="foo">
</div>

 div#foo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px red solid;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    /*if you want to play animation for once onlye then you can use forwards instade of infinite.*/
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0% {
        border: 3px red solid
    }
    25% {
        border: 3px #000 solid
    }
    75% {
        border: 3px blue solid
    }
    100% {
        border: 3px green solid
    }
}
@keyframes mymove {
    0% {
        border: 3px red solid
    }
    25% {
        border: 3px #000 solid
    }
    75% {
        border: 3px blue solid
    }
    100% {
        border: 3px green solid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be easier to use a CSS animation.  This one is set to run infinitely @ 5s per animation:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello, check out my border that is ALWAYS changing color :)</div>
```

Hope this helps!